# Codemagic automatic app signing fails for ios

Tags: ios, flutter, dart, codemagic

ios automatic app signing is enabled and apple developer portal connected. But, ios build fails:

```
ERROR! Did not find matching provisioning profiles for code signing!
> xcodebuild -workspace /Users/builder/clone/ios/Runner.xcworkspace -scheme Runner -archivePath /Users/builder/build.xcarchive -config Release archive COMPILER_INDEX_STORE_ENABLE=NO DEVELOPMENT_TEAM='' CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY='iPhone Developer'
❌  error: Signing for "Runner" requires a development team. Select a development team in the Signing & Capabilities editor. (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')
```

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 7):

Finally, I solved the issue by manually adding team name under `TargetAttributes` in ios/Runner.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj as following:

```
TargetAttributes = {
    97C146ED1CF9000F007C117D = {
        CreatedOnToolsVersion = 7.3.1;
        LastSwiftMigration = 0910;
        DevelopmentTeam = SSSSSSS3;
    };
};
```

You can find `DEVELOPMENT_TEAM` name in Apple Developer Portal -> Identifiers -> App ID Prefix.